# Autocorrect (or macro) for general case: uuu,u to uuuu,

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Example: I like thi,s

I am hoping for a macro or autocorrect that does not require me to manually enter every word.

I can’t find any information on replacing items for the general case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a wildcard find and replace - each "part" is enclosed in round brackets.  The first part is anything except a space, the second part is the comma, and the final part is also not a space (as comma normally followed by a space so don't want to change those).

The screenshot below shows what worked for me - reordering the parts in the replace to keep the first part (letter before comma), then the last part (letter after the comma), then the middle part (the comma).  Because you have excluded from find where space is on either side of comma (the [! ] means not space), it should leave alone "this, and that" but pick up "thi,s and that".
[image]